# Collapasble tree using divs to hide child branches using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a collapasbe tree using divs, which I've got working fine, the part i'm having trouble with is, if I click on the any parent branch to expand I want the rest of the branchs to hide and to re-appear when I collapse them.

```
- parent Item - if I expand this
-- child item - if I expand this
--- item - and so on
--- item - and so on
-- child item - hide this
-- child item - hide this
- parent Item - hide this
- parent Item -hide this
```

I have a working example here

https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/5dtgb91t/

I've updated the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/5dtgb91t/2/

I can now get all the parent child ids, just trying to work out how to keep the active branch to show and hide the rest.

```
//Gets the ID for the parent - branch0
var getBranchParentID = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop("id");

//Goes through each branch in the parent - branch0_0,branch0_1 etc
$('#' + getBranchParentID).children().children('.branch').each(function() {
var bell = $(this).attr('id');

// if the branch is active hide all other branches, if I click back to make it not active all the branches should show
var isActiveChild = $('#'+bell).hasClass('active');

if(isActiveChild){
  $(this).show();
}else {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

});

update - Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/5dtgb91t/10/

Update cleanup - https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/5dtgb91t/12/

Comment: the thing you want to do is already working on first level...right?

Comment: yes, but it isn't the best solution

Comment: so what exact effect you want?

Comment: I think this is good, what do u need help with???

Comment: Does this help? `$(this).parent().siblings('.active').find('.collapsable').click();`